# How do I path through C:\Users\Myname\Desktop

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a specific program (in python) and when I use the path command and say I want to go to the desktop, it's in C:\Users\Myname\Desktop. And if someone else downloads the file it won't be able to path because I do not know the users name.

Comment: Could you give an example of your code which is accessing the file?

Comment: Do Note: That If You Use The Above Method You Need To Add A Check to see if a user has Linux Or Windows Operating Systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just `username` you can use this

```
os.environ["HOMEPATH"].split("\\")[-1]
# output: Afshar Sharifi
```

But if you want the whole path to desktop better to use thid

```
os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop')
# output: C:\Users\Afshar Sharifi\Desktop
```

Comment: Thanks, just wondering how am I supposed to incorporate this into my code?